# NameError - unitilaized constant - only in production

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a ruby on rails app that is hosted on heroku.  When I try to create an item running it in "development" mode, everything works great and there are no issues.  However, when I switch the app to run in "production" mode I'm getting the following.

This was a Ruby 2.2.x upgraded to 2.5.x and rails 4.1 upgraded to 5.2.

Any ideas or suggestions on why this is failing in production but works fine in development?

```
Started POST "/items" for 1.2.3.4 at 2020-10-19 03:22:06 +0000
2020-10-19T03:22:06.870055+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ItemController#create as HTML
2020-10-19T03:22:06.870358+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {###Redacted##}
2020-10-19T03:22:06.926046+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 54ms (ActiveRecord: 15.8ms)
2020-10-19T03:22:06.999133+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-10-19T03:22:06.998984 #11]  INFO -- : Sending event 18b887c876d4524b5cd46849a98aaeb1 to Sentry
2020-10-19T03:22:07.271068+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2020-10-19T03:22:07.271478+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError (uninitialized constant #<Class:0x0000567238d68165>::Slug):
2020-10-19T03:22:07.276183+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2020-10-19T03:22:07.276248+00:00 app[web.1]: app/models/item.rb:305:in `name_to_slug'
2020-10-19T03:22:07.276248+00:00 app[web.1]: app/models/item.rb:293:in `generate_slug'
```

Comment: You can SSH into to the production box with `heroku run rails c` and then try to manually run the code which is causing the error. This will show you more information about what's happening. It might have to do a file not being required or something - I don't remember the exact details but I think development and production can load files in a different order or something. Maybe you just need an extra `require` somewhere.

Comment: Are you missing an environment variable in production? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs I don't think so .. on Heroku if I change RACK_ENV and RAILS_ENV from production to development it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked this back to a custom class that was located in the "lib" folder.  Moving from Rails 4 to 5 it seems like some behaviors changed with loading custom classes which needed to be accounted for:

https://gist.github.com/maxivak/381f1e964923f1d469c8d39da8e2522f